# Pre-populating fields in Wrapper classes

Tags: unit-test, wrapper-class

How can I access fields inside an inner wrapper class to pre-populate the fields?

My Controller:

```
public class customClass {
    public List<wrapperClass> wrapperName {get; set;}

    public customClass() {
      // some code 
    }

    public wrapperClass {
        public customObj co {get; private set;}
        public integer ident {get; private set;}

        public wrapperClass(integer inIdent) {
            ident = inIdent;
            co = new customObj();
        }
    }

}
```

Test Controller:

this is my TestClass

```
@isTest
public class TestSomeClass{ 

    static testMethod void Test_SomeClass_onAcct() {

        //Creating a full account
        createAccountClass c = new createAccountClass();
        c.CreateFullAcct();

        //Creating custom object and assigning account id
        customObject__c co = new customObject__c();
        c.account_id__c= c.id;

        Test.startTest();

        PageReference pageRef1 = Page.visualforcePage;

        pageRef1.getParameters().put('AcctParam',c.id);
        pageRef1.getParameters().put('RetUrl',c.id);

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef1);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(c.id);
        HotTopicActionsMultiCreator Controller1 = new HotTopicActionsMultiCreator(c.id);

        controller1 = new OuterWrapper(sc1);

        controller1.class1();
        controller1.class2();
        controller1.class3();

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Right now I'm receiving the error "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [dateField1__c, ownerField__c]

I tried creating the inner class to pre-populate the fields by writing.....

```
controller1.outerWrapper wrapperTest = new controller1.outerWrapper(1);
```

But I receive the error "Invalid Type"

From my understanding you can create objects with pre-populate fields by writing...

```
SomeObject customName = new SomeObject(field1='one',field2='two');
```

How would we go about doing this for a custom object inside a wrapper class?

Thanks for any and all help.

Cheers,

Andrew H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be setting those values in your unit test:

```
controller1.HTA[0].Target_date__c = Date.today();
controller1.HTA[0].Action_Owner__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
```

Assuming those fields are required, and the user should be filling them out, you'll want to just populate the values as you would if a user were using the page.